# Font family not showing on android device

Tags: android, css, webfonts

I am using this "Century Gothic" font in my ionic1 app but this font is displaying in browser but not in android device.Please help!!!
I tried this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Century Gothic";
  src: url("../fonts/gothic.eot");
  src: url("../fonts/gothic.eot") format("embedded-opentype"), 
url("../fonts/gothic.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/gothic.woff") 
format("woff"), url("../fonts/gothic.woff") format("woff"), 
url("../fonts/gothic.svg") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal; }

  p {
  font-family: 'Century Gothic' !important;
  }
```

Comment: What internet browser are you using? The built in one ("Internet") doesn't seem to get updates as often as the regular ones do. If you install the Chrome or Firefox app, does it work there?

Comment: Thanx for your concern....my problem is solved now

Comment: OK, how did you solve the problem? If this is something that can help other people, you should post it a an answer.

Comment: yes..... i did it

Answer (score 1):

add this code in ionic.css

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Century Gothic";
src: url("../fonts/gothic.eot");
  src: url("../fonts/gothic.eot") format("embedded-opentype"), 
url("../fonts/gothic.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/gothic.woff") 
format("woff"), url("../fonts/gothic.woff") format("woff"), 
url("../fonts/gothic.svg") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal; }
```

and then this to style.css

```
 body {
  font-family: 'Century Gothic' !important;
  }
```

Comment: But what is the difference between this and your original CSS? And by the way, it has `url("../fonts/gothic.woff") format("woff")` duplicated; I'm assuming one of those should be `woff2`.

Comment: i added this one to ionic.css.....previously i was adding it to style.css the it was not working properly.....

Comment: Ah, OK. If that is the solution, that should be in the answer itself, not in a comment.